# Unable to login to any php system on IIS after moving to new server

Tags: php, iis, wordpress

My host moved to a new IIS server. My website is ASP.Net MVC based. Plus it also has wordpress and question2answer php systems under subfolders /blog and /qa. These websites are showing all pages correctly. But I am unable to login to these systems using same user name / password. It does not show any error. Nor does it log any error.

Any ideas?

Comment: "I am unable to login to these systems", which systems? Please name them explicitly. "using same user name / password", what user name and password? Different systems can have different accounts, so not a surprise.

Comment: I mean I am not able to login to wordpress and question2answer.

Comment: Don't save your words when asking a question please. What kind of problem when you attempted to log in? Could you see the login page or not? Could you type the correct user credentials? Without such basic information, no one can help. Use screen shots if you don't know how to share details.

Comment: Sorry. The login page reappears as if loaded fresh, without any error.  The user credentials are fine. I even reset it from database (MD5) and tried the password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. Finally I found the reason for this.

The Application Pool in IIS associated with my site was in Integrated Pipeline mode. I changed that to Classic Pipeline mode and everything started working.

Thanks